# 'Error: database "root" does not exist' in Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

I am running NodeJS microservice that talks to Postgres database. But when I am trying to start the service I am getting below error. I do not have any idea why this error is popping up.

Error:

```
   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection(rejection id:1): error: database “root” does not exist
```

My DB connection details:

```
  const pg = require(“pg”);
  const client = new pg.Client({
            host: “txslmxxxda6z”,
            user: “mom”,
            password: “mom”,
            db: “mom”,
            port: 5025
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this myself. The issue is in connection config. It should be database but not db so this was causing the issue. PFB answer

```
 const client = new pg.Client({
        host: “txslmoxxx6z”,
        user: “mom”,
        password: “mom”,
        //change db to database
        database: “mom”,
        port: 5025
 });
```